# VS2017 GAC Microsoft Team Foundation DLLl reference issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, gac

I have an app that was written on an older PC which had GAC references to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItems.Client.dll

Both were v12

My newer machine has v15 of these files.  When I tried to reference them on my dev machine I'm not finding them in Extensions where I expected to see them.

Further hacking at it if I manually change the version if the project file I can build the EXE but when I deploy the exe to where it runs that machine is saying it can't load v15 of the files even though I can see them in the GAC  "c:\windows\microsoft.net\assemblies"

What am I missing or doing wrong here.

Comment: Try a binding redirect (a "bindingRedirect" element in your config file).  It may/may not help

Comment: Not sure that will help, when it tells me it can't find v15 even though I can see it installed in the GAC